# jQuery - Add/Remove Required to an input

Tags: jquery, input, required

I try to add/remove the "required" element from inputs depending on the value of a select. Hiding/Showing works as a charm but nothing happen for the required element (both adding or removing). Same issue with "prop" instead of "attr".

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label  " for="id_Commission_Type">Commission Type</label>
  <div class=" ">
    <select name="Commission_Type" class=" form-control" required id="id_Commission_Type">
      <option value="" selected>---------</option>
      <option value="Percentage">Percentage</option>
      <option value="Amount">Amount</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label  " for="id_Commission_Percentage">Commission Percentage</label>
  <div class=" ">
    <input type="number" name="Commission_Percentage" step="any" class=" form-control" id="id_Commission_Percentage">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">    
  <label class="control-label  " for="id_Commission_Amount">Commission Amount</label>
  <div class=" ">
    <input type="number" name="Commission_Amount" step="any" class=" form-control" id="id_Commission_Amount">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#id_Commission_Percentage").prop("required", true);
        $("#id_Commission_Type").change(function() {
            var Commission_Type = $("#id_Commission_Type").val();
            if (Commission_Type == "Percentage") {
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").hide();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Amount']").hide();
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").removeAttr("required");

                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").show();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Percentage']").show();
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").prop("required", true);

            }
            else if (Commission_Type == "Amount") {
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").hide();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Percentage']").hide();
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").removeAttr("required");

                $("#id_Commission_Amount").show();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Amount']").show();
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").attr("required", true);

            };
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Haven't you try:

.attr('required', 'required'); ?

Does console say something?

Comment: Hi @ZottoZ, can you paste your html code?

Comment: I just added the HTML code related to the script. I tried attr("required", "required") and it did nothing. The console show no errors;

Comment: @ZottoZ the code you provided works for me. Perhaps required doesn't work with `input type=number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#id_Commission_Type").change(function() {
            var Commission_Type = $("#id_Commission_Type").val();
            if (Commission_Type == "Percentage") {
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").hide();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Amount']").hide();
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").removeAttr("required");

                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").show();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Percentage']").show();
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").attr("required", true);

            }
            else if (Commission_Type == "Amount") {
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").hide();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Percentage']").hide();
                $("#id_Commission_Percentage").removeAttr("required");

                $("#id_Commission_Amount").show();
                $("[for='id_Commission_Amount']").show();
                $("#id_Commission_Amount").attr("required", true);

            };
        });

    });
```

In other words: try `$(document).ready(function() {...})` instead of `$(function() {...}`.

Comment: ...and the difference is...?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If I'm not mistaken the two structures are equivalent.

Comment: @ZottoZ they are two structures totally different. The first is called when the dom is just load, the second is called when the dom in not loaded, so the second can generate problems.

Comment: @ZottoZ i edit my answer try to  change  $("#id_Commission_Percentage").prop("required", true); in  $("#id_Commission_Percentage").attr("required", true); andchange also $("#id_Commission_Percentage").prop("required", true); at the start in the same way! the first line. Now it must work

Comment: Well I just tried with Chrome and didn't worked but with Edge it worked ??!

Comment: I already clicked on the "V" (accepted answer) .. Is there something else to do ?